# php message queue based on named-pipe halts

Tags: php, message-queue, named-pipes

i have the following (simplified) server + client message queue system.
the core of the system is the named pipe, created with `posix_mkfifo`.
there are 3 processes that use the client (publisher) to write messages to this queue.
the problem is that on a high concurrency scenario, one publisher halts and doesn't respond.

**server**

```
while(true)
{
   while($input = trim(fgets($pipe)))
   {
      stream_set_blocking($pipe, false); $messages[] = $input;
   }

   foreach($messages as &$message)
   {
      // process... (each iteration takes about ~5-8 seconds)
      unset($message);
   }

   echo 'nothing to do, waiting...', PHP_EOL; ob_flush();
   
   stream_set_blocking($pipe, true);
}
```

**client**

```
// logic...
file_put_contents($pipe_path, json_encode($job) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

i tried to emulate the problem like this:

```
while($index < 512)
{
   // publish job
   
   if(rand() % 2)
   {
      usleep(30 * 1000); // sleep for 30ms sometimes
   }
   
   $index++;
}
```

this usually fails @ iteration 98 or 195.
is there somekind of data size limit on the named pipe or what could cause the halting?
i'm using centos 7.9.2009.